# Installing SQL Server Reporting Service (SSRS) 2005 on machine having 2008 version already, possible/how?

Tags: installation, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I have a computer (windows 7) which already has SSRS 2008 installed. We also need to install SSRS 2005 on it. When I run installer for 2005 I see "reporting service" option greyed out. What could be the reason? How can install ssrs 2005 on this machine?

Answer (score 1):

They can certainly coexist, I have had servers with 3 versions on them whilst migrating reports.

It's possible that you've installed it with the same instance name which would then make reporting services think that it is already installed and not let you. There could also be an issue with IIS ports.

When I've needed to do this I've installed them the other way around (2005 first then 2008 then 2008 R2) which might be an issue as well due to shared components.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you would want to use 2005? Any existing reports that you may have that are 2005 should work fine on 2008.

As Davos indicates they will coexist but you would have to uninstall 2008, then install 2005, and then reinstall 2008.